# Best way to convert Map<Object, Optional<Object>> to Map<Object, Object>?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm building a layer in between two sets of APIs that I have no control over (i.e., even though it's not the best use of optional to do this, I can't make contract changes). It takes in a hash map that gives me `<Object, Optional<Object>>`, does some processing with that hash map, and then returns the revised `<Object, Object>` hash map to be used by another service.

What's the best way to extract the values from the optional and throw an error when that optional is empty? Right now I have:

```
itemsMap.forEach((key, value) -> value.map(Optional::of).orElseThrow(() -> 
    new WhateverMyExceptionIs("Exception Message")));
```

But that doesn't transform the optional into the value of the optional.

Comment: Yeah, that looks good. Otherwise you can ignore the empty optionals. Therefore the program will not throw an exception and the non-empty values are used.

Comment: That’s a bad interface design alright. Of course you can make the transformation (which is good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output map had the same type you could use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) overwrite the values in place.

Since the input and output maps have different types, you can use a stream to map the entries and create a new map:

```
Map<Object, Object> newMap = itemsMap
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getKey(),
        e -> e.getValue().orElseThrow(
            () -> new WhateverMyExceptionIs("Exception Message")
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s not completely clear what you want the result to be, in particular not what you want in case one of the `Optional`s is empty. For this code snippet I have assumed that you want to leave those entries out.

```
    Map<Object, Optional<Object>> originalMap = Map.of("Key 1", Optional.of(Integer.valueOf(2)),
            Integer.valueOf(3), Optional.empty(),
            "Key 4", Optional.of("Value 4"));
    Map<Object, Object> targetMap = originalMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().orElseThrow()));
    System.out.println(targetMap);
```

Output is:

> {Key 1=2, Key 4=Value 4}

I usually tell folks to avoid `Optional.isPresent()` as low-level. In this case I would use it. I don’t consider it bad code on my part, but rather a sign of bad API design as you already said.

In case you prefer not to use `Optional.isPresent()`, there is a way without it. The code gets less readable IMHO:

```
    Map<Object, Object> targetMap = originalMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), v)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

The result is the same as before.